# How do you stop an Apache Storm message from replaying in the middle of the topology?

Tags: java, apache-storm

So we have a topology that is linear.  Lets say that bolt 2 does some jaxb parsing and it cannot parse the xml for some reason. We don't want it to go to bolt 3 or 4.  We just want to stop the process.

How do we stop the process?

Comment: so what you want is skip those messages which bolt is not able to parse?

Comment: Yes.  We don't want to replay the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ack the incoming tuple without emitting anything.

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    try {
        // process tuple here
        collector.emit("your_stream",tuple,new Values(value));
    } catch(Execption e) {
        // don't emit
    } finally {
        collector.ack(tuple);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so since the "topology" for each message is built as it is run, bolt 3 and 4 do not have to ack.  So bolt 2 fails, acks, but does not emit.  The spout says, hey, 2 is done.  But how does the spout know it does not have to wait for 3 and 4?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly how it works. bolt3 and bolt4 only get "involved" if the current input tuple is used as an anchor in bolt2.

Comment: So the spout "knows" when we emit to 3 and 4 and since we didn't, it doesn't wait...

Comment: Yes. Each time a tuple is used as an anchor, this tuple gets "registered" by an acker task which than waits to receive an "ack" for this tuple. If no ack arrives within the timeout, the acker sends an fail-message to the spout -- if all acks got received by an acker it sends an ack-message to the spout.